# Qt transparency not working on Gnome

Tags: python, qt, transparency, pyside

Transparency settings on my PySide application are not working on Gnome (2.28.2) but work fine on Windows and Mac, any reason ?

It displays a black background instead.

Here is an example code:

```
form PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class RoundWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(RoundWindow, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()



    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)



    def sizeHint(self):

        return QtCore.QSize(300,300)



    def paintEvent(self, event):

        qp = QtGui.QPainter()

        qp.begin(self)

        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing);

        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen);

        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 127));

        qp.drawEllipse(0, 0, 300, 300);

        qp.end()





rw = RoundWindow()

rw.show()
```

This is very frustrating. Any ideas are welcome !

Thx !

Comment: I am using gnome 3.26.2 and it works correctly.

Comment: I am on 2.28.2 (at work), Do you know if there are some settings in Gnome that would enable/disable transparency ?